# WebdriverIO: Not able to access browser capabilities when using multiRemote

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have setup up my `wdio.conf.js` to use multiple browsers in my tests as described on the [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io) website. (*the capabilities are defined as an object, if using multiremote feature*)

In my spec file, when I try to perform an action, such as `MyFirefoxBrowser.url('https://myUrl')` ... (what is happening?)

**!Note:** When I refer to the `browser` object directly, both Chrome and Firefox instances are spawned, as expected.

I have tried referring the `wdio.conf.js` file inside my spec file using require, but it didn't work.

**Spec file** (`.js`):

```
describe('webdriver.io page', () => {
    it('should have the right title', () => {  

        myFirefoxBrowser.url('https://webdriver.io');
        const title = myFirefoxBrowser.getTitle()
        assert.strictEqual(title, 'WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js')
     });
});
```

**Capabilities** (as defined in the `wdio.conf.js`):

```
capabilities: {
    myChromeBrowser: {
        capabilities: {
            browserName1: 'chrome'
        }
    },
    myFirefoxBrowser: {
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'firefox'
        }
    }
},
```

**Error:**

> ReferenceError: mychromeBrowser is not defined

**Expected Results:** Only the Firefox browser should navigate to the requested url.

Answer (score 0):

`myChromeBrowser` != `mychromeBrowser`. Check this. Also not sure what do you want to do with this. `browser` is object for every browser and if you want to decide on type of it, you can via `browser.capabilities`
and you will get object

```
{ acceptInsecureCerts: false,
  browserName: 'chrome',
  browserVersion: '78.0.3904.97',
  chrome:
   { chromedriverVersion:
      '78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800})',
     userDataDir: '/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.Ihm6cA' },
  'goog:chromeOptions': { debuggerAddress: 'localhost:45423' },
  networkConnectionEnabled: false,
  pageLoadStrategy: 'normal',
  platformName: 'linux',
  proxy: {},
  setWindowRect: true,
  strictFileInteractability: false,
  timeouts: { implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000 },
  unhandledPromptBehavior: 'dismiss and notify' }
```

You **should** use `browser`.

Answer (score 0):

`capabilities` should be defined as an array

```
// wdio.conf.js
exports.config = {
    // ...
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }, {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // ...
        proxy: {
            proxyType: "manual",
            httpProxy: "corporate.proxy:8080",
            socksUsername: "codeceptjs",
            socksPassword: "secret",
            noProxy: "127.0.0.1,localhost"
        },
        // ...
    }],
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I think you have a typo. It should be browserName in capabilities.myChromeBrowser and not browserName1. Otherwise the code should do as you want.

```
capabilities: 

    {
        myChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        myFirefoxBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            }
        }

},
```